# Check if flowLayoutPanel is empty in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, null, label, flowlayoutpanel

I want to make an error label come up when my flowLayoutPanel is empty, but i don't know how to check that the flowLayoutPanel is empty. This is my current code:

```
private void flowLayoutPanel1_ControlRemoved(object sender, ControlEventArgs e)
        {
            if (flowLayoutPanel1.Controls == null)
            {
                customtoolwarning.Visible = true;
            }
            else
            {
                customtoolwarning.Visible = false;
            }
        }
```

Please Help,

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
private void flowLayoutPanel1_ControlRemoved(object sender, ControlEventArgs e)
        {
            if (flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Count > 0)
            {
                customtoolwarning.Visible = true;
            }
            else
            {
                customtoolwarning.Visible = false;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem you're running into is you're checking `Controls` for `null` to determine if it's empty.  The `Controls` property won't ever be `null` but instead will be non-null and have 0 length when empty.  For example

```
if (flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Count == 0) {
  // It's empty
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lblNoContacts.Visible = (flowLayoutPanel.Controls.Count == 0) ? true : false;
```

Comment: Essentially nothing, it does exactly the same thing - just another way of writing it :)